# Does Sunkeeper Tarim only reset the base stats?

Tags: hearthstone

At first I assumed, after [Tarim](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Sunkeeper_Tarim) is played all other minions would be 3/3 s. But I am pretty sure my murlocs broke that rule, because they could still buff each other.

So, does Tarim only alter the base stats? Does a buffed minion remain buffed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any minion that provides a constant aura buff to other minions, like Murloc Warleader or Stormwind Champion, will still add its aura after stat changes have occurred. Thus, any stat changes, such as humility, Following the Rules, etc, will only reduce to one after the aura giver dies.

Comment: So, if I have a very big vicious fledgling, or used blessings of kings, these buffs will be gone?

Comment: Yes, because those are inherent, single use stat increases to that particular minion rather than aura buffs provided by other minions. Think of it this way: playing defender of argus would make a 3/3 a 4/4 with taunt, and then Tarim would overwrite those stats and revert it to a 3/3. However, something like Dire Wolf Alpha *always* provides a +1 attack buff to adjacent minions, thus a 3/3 with a Wolf would become a 4/3 and remain a 4/3 even under the effects of Tarim. This is because the argus buff is given to a minion, whereas the wolf buff is a result of another minion's aura.

Comment: @Ludi: To extend the answer, there is a way to turn aura buffs into permanent stat boosts. E.g. say you have a 5/5 on the board, which is now a 6/5 due to a raid leader. The enemy then plays crazy alchemist on the 6/5. The 6/5 becomes a 5/6 (notice that the +1 attack _aura_ buff is converted to a _permanent_ +1 health stat), and the raid leader then turns the 5/6 into a 6/6 (because it is still giving the +1 attack aura buff). If the raid leader dies, the 6/6 will go back to being a 5/6 (keeping the health buff), not a 5/5.